# Run Style Cop options not visible after nuget install vs2012

Tags: c#, stylecop

After installing Style Cop form nuget package the options for files "Run StyleCop" are not visible. Is there a way for them to show up without performing normal StyleCop install?
I'm using Visual Studio 2012

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as a start.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install StyleCop's Visual Studio integration from [the project site](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/).  Downloading [the package from NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/StyleCop/) just gives you the libraries to create custom rules.